# What's the difference between "Don't fight me." and "Don't fight with me."?

Tags: prepositions, difference, transitivity

I want to know the difference between "Don't fight me." and "Don't fight with me.".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentence "**Don't fight me**" suggests a physical fight and the sentence **Don't fight with me** suggests a non-physical fight such as an argument, I would usually say **Don't argue with me** to make it more explicit although **Don't fight with me** is also a valid phrase.

Comment: I am not sure. But This answer is equal with the one that I found on another website. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think one implies a physical fight and one does not?  To this US English speaker, there's no such implication.

Comment: It does of course depend on the context, Lucian Sava's answer is also valid if the context is right. However to me the words don't fight me suggests a physical fight because it is not that often that a non physical fight is called a fight, it is usually called an argument(in the UK anyway). The addition of the word "with" to me suggests a non physical fight because it is rare that someone says don't fight **with** me if it is physical.

Answer (score 2):

The two sentences may have the same meaning if **with** is understood as **against** or opposed meanings if **with** is understood as **alongside**.

Consequently, whether they have the same meaning or not it's entirely dependent on a larger context.